# Display title of all custom posts from same taxonomy term on a custom post template

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I have a custom post and I want to display other custom post data from within the same taxonomy term on the template. Ideally i'd like to use a `foreach();` loop as this fits in with the other loops within the theme.

I could declare the term within the config below but I'd like it to be a little more flexible as there are a number of terms with the taxonomy.

For example, I have products within a taxomony. On each product template I want to be able to see other products within the same taxonomy.

I'm struggling to output the data. Here's what I have so far which isn't giving me what I want:

```
<?php
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$products = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'my_custom_post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(  
        array(  
            'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',  
            'field' => 'slug',  
            'terms' => $term  
        )  
    )
));
?>

<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
  <?php echo $product->post_title; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Is it possible to do this using the `foreach();` loop? And is it then possible to add a class to the 'current' custom post type?

Comment: `terms` expects an integer, string, or array, you're passing an object.

Comment: @Milo Any idea what value would need to be passed? I guess I need find the ID of the term?